# Tangent plane in higher dimensions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, plane-geometry

How would I go about finding the tangent plane to the equation $(cosh x_1)^2 = x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2$ at the point $(0,0,\frac 1{\sqrt 2},\frac 1{\sqrt 2})$?

I tried to find it by having $f=-(cosh x_1)^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2$ and then finding the gradient of $f$.

Then I set up the equation of the plane as $a(x_1-0)+b(x_2-0)+c(x_3-\frac 1{\sqrt 2})+d(x_4-\frac 1{\sqrt 2})=0$ where $a,b,c,d$ are the partial derivatives of $f$ for $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ respectively. After doing the plugging and chugging my final equation for the plane was $\frac 2{\sqrt 2}x_3+\frac 2{\sqrt 2}x_4=0$ which just doesn't look quite right.

Also, once I find the equation of the plane, how could I put the equation in the form of $(0,0,\frac 1{2^{1/2}},\frac 1{2^{1/2}})+span(v_1,v_2,v_3)$?

Answer (score 0):

Your method seems sound, and I agree with you on the values of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.  But what doesn't “look right” about your hyperplane is that it doesn't pass through $\left(0,0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.

Your normal form of the equation for the hyperplane needs a nonzero parameter on the right-hand side.  You can find the value of that parameter by evaluating the left-hand side at $\left(0,0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.  So:
$$
    \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} x_3 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} x_4 = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\implies x_3 + x_4 = \sqrt{2}
$$
Your $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ are any three linearly independent vectors whose third and fourth components add to zero.  They span the nullspace of the $1\times 4$ matrix 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c & d \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{bmatrix}
\longrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
In linear algebra parlance, $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_4$ are free variables, while $x_3 = -x_4$.  We get one vector from setting each of the free variables equal to $1$ and the others to zero, one at a time.  If $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = x_4 = 0$, we get $v_1 = (1,0,0,0)$.  If $x_2 = 1$ and $x_1 = x_4 = 0$, we get $v_2 = (0,1,0,0)$.  If $x_4 = 1$ and $x_1 = x_2 = 0$, we get $v_3 = (0,0,-1,1)$.

Comment: Oh my apologies I copied my own answer incorrectly. The equation I found was $\frac 2{\sqrt 2}x_3+\frac 2{\sqrt 2}x_4=2$. Would this actually be correct?

Comment: @E.Hurd: That is the same as mine.  because $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Also, what was your method for determining what linearly independent vectors would work?

Comment: @E.Hurd once you have the reduced row echelon form of a matrix, it's a straightforward linear algebra algorithm to find a basis of the nullspace.  I've filled in the details.